# Office 365 password encrypting in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, office365, exchangewebservices

I am working on a mobile app (android, ios). Users login in the mobile app by entering email and password of office 365 and authentication is done through php-ews (exchange web services for office 365). We will be using few calendar and email retrieval web services in the mobile app.

What is the best way to encrypt the password while storing it in the backend database?

Comment: Dont Store password in your database. If you made an O365 authentication, you use an OAUTH2 authentication process. So you should just save the Refresh Token. No need to encrypt it

Comment: can the OAUTH2 be used for on-premises exchange using EWS?

Comment: I don't know about on-premise exchange, but I have already built a OAUTH2 function in to php-ews. Give it a try, see if it works https://github.com/Garethp/php-ews/blob/master/examples/basic/authenticatingWithOAuth.php

Comment: Prassee, no need to write a correction in a comment. You can [edit] your question. I have done that now.